# Power steering issues

Tags: ford, steering, focus

I have a 2007 ford focus and the power steering is making noises and after I shut off the car it starts to leak fluid around the cap.  I have taken it to the shop and they changed the pump, resev., and flushed it and it still does it.  I think it is a leak somewhere because it causes the fluid to be foamy.  What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This morning my car wouldn't turn at all and had to have it towed to the shop .  .  I told him to pull a vac on the system like you said so I guess we will find out tomorrow.

Comment: I have the same problem I change the o rings and still get it air and foaming any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a leak on the return line or at the reservoir return o ring. Have them pull vacuum on the system and see if it will hold. This will also bleed the air out of the system if there isn't a leak. You should also use Mercon V instead of the generic power steering fluid if you aren't already.

The reason the fluid overflows like that is because of the aeration of the fluid and the power steering pump putting pressure on the system.

Comment: So I understand, is it with the aeration of the fluid there's air built up in the system. While under pressure it's fine, but once the system has stopped pumping, the pressure goes away and the air expands, causing the overflow?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Correct.